# Resizing a front page header on Hestia theme (Elementor)

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, elementor

I'm working off of a free Hestia theme with the Elementor editor, and I've run into a problem. When I started, I used a background image that worked fine within the background fill style of the theme. However, the client switched to a banner image with the content already populated. This banner required that the CSS switch to a `contain` background type due to the short height/full width dimensions and the header's full screen design.

However, when I tried to add CSS to set the height to something that would hold it, the headers broke on all subsequent pages. I requested and got a more square image, but I'm now getting large left and right margins. Is there a way to get this to fit properly within this theme? I started building this in August 2018 and this has been a persistent issue.